# SMTP & Python & Socket: Can't send DATA

Tags: python, sockets, smtp

For learning purposes I want to use only sockets and SSL library, so I managed to connect to google.com and log in to my account. The problem is that I didn't manage to send any email and I cannot understand the reason.
This is the output, so until `DATA` everything is correct. Thus I think that the problem must be in the lines after `.send("DATA"....)`.
I'm using python 3, therefore I need every time to `.encode()` and `.decode()`.

```
import ssl
import base64
from socket import *
import sys

cc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
cc.connect(("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
print(cc.recv(1024).decode())

cc.send(('helo tester.com\r\n').encode())
print(cc.recv(1024).decode())
cc.send(('starttls\r\n').encode())
print(cc.recv(1024).decode())

############# Authentication #############
scc = ssl.wrap_socket(cc, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)

scc.send(('auth login\r\n').encode())
print(scc.recv(1024).decode())

scc.send((base64.b64encode(('francesco.zuppichini@gmail.com').encode()))+('\r\n').encode())
print(scc.recv(1024).decode())

scc.send((base64.b64encode(('********').encode()))+('\r\n').encode())
print(scc.recv(1024).decode())

############# EMAIL #############
scc.send(("MAIL FROM: <francesco.zuppichini@gmail.com>" + '\r\n').encode())
print(scc.recv(1024).decode())
scc.send(("RCPT to: <francesco.zuppichini@gmail.com>" + '\r\n').encode())
print(scc.recv(1024).decode())
scc.send(("DATA" + '\r\n').encode())
print(scc.recv(1024).decode())
# start to send the Data
scc.send(("Subject: Test!" + '\r\n').encode())
scc.send(("From: francesco.zuppichini@gmail.com" + '\r\n').encode())
scc.send(("To: francesco.zuppichini@gmail.com" + '\r\n').encode())
scc.send(("Ciaooone" + '\r\n').encode())
scc.send(("'\r\n'.'\r\n'").encode())
print(scc.recv(1024).decode())
############# Exit #############
scc.send(("QUIT" + '\r\n').encode())
print(scc.recv(1024).decode())

scc.close()
cc.close()
```

OUTPUT:

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP bg10sm91176924wjb.46 - gsmtp

250 smtp.gmail.com at your service

220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS

334 VXNlcm5hbWU6

334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6

235 2.7.0 Accepted

250 2.1.0 OK bg10sm91176924wjb.46 - gsmtp

250 2.1.5 OK bg10sm91176924wjb.46 - gsmtp

354  Go ahead bg10sm91176924wjb.46 - gsmtp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> scc.send(("'\r\n'.'\r\n'").encode())

You don't send `\r\n.\r\n` here like you probably planned to mark the end of the mail but you've send `'\r\n'.'\r\n'`, i.e. with the single quotes.